# Disable Future method from running twice

Tags: apex, future

I have a future method that i call in afterInsert and AfterUpdate Triggers.

i want to disable the running of the AfterUpdate call if AfterInsert ran before it, if i do not disable it i get the following error:

> System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future or
>   batch method:
>   CaseTriggerHandler.caseMilestoneUpdateForListView(Set)

how can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time you want to call a future method, you can just check to see if it's allowed:

```
if(!System.isFuture() && !System.isBatch()) {
  doFutureMethod();
}
```

<strike>There's other ways you can arrange this, but I think this is one of the easiest ways to prevent breaking governor limits (Limits.getLimitFutureCalls() should return 0 when future methods are not allowed).</strike>

Looks like this technique is currently flawed. The Limits method is returning the synchronous limit instead of the correct value (0). I'm going to go file a bug with someone, but in the meantime, the above code should work.

Comment: Another option would be to `System.isFuture()`, I liked your approach better.

Comment: Limit.getLimitFutureCalls returns the number of remaining number of future calls. How will this return zero as the question is not talking about anything related to governor limit. Please elaborate @sfdcfox.

Comment: @the_phantom The limits class is supposed to return a dynamic value based on the current context. For example, when you call Limits.getLimitCpuTime(), it returns 10000 in synchronous code and 60000 in asynchronous code. However, it looks like limits.getlimitfuturecalls isn't working that way. I'll amend my answer, but I'm going to go file a bug.

Comment: @sfdcbox, that was my concern. Thank you. I hope the bug gets fixed, if they consider it a bug.